# Adding parity to binary in other words Hamming code

Tags: c

I have a binary number of 01000001
I would like to add 4 parity numbers to that binary code.
I have an array of 8 bits unsigned char arr[8];
each index has digit of the bit
ex:
arr[0] = 0

Using hammingcode so it should be 12 digits with the parity (8 + 4parity)

p[0] = sequence[10] + sequence[8] + sequence[6] + sequence[4] + sequence[2]

```
What i'm getting is 1110 and it should be 1001 for parity
```

Comment: Are you trying to produce a `0` or `1` in `p[0]`? Because `sequence[1] + sequence[3] + sequence[5] + sequence[7]` could be as high as 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what language you're using but it seems to use 0-based array indexing.
However, you are indexing `arr` from `arr[1]` to `arr[8]`.

Comment: Using C, Ok it works but i get a non glyph character values